# Adding two numbers from EditText fields

Tags: android, kotlin

```kotlin
fun add(num1: EditText, num2: EditText){
    try {
        num1.toString().toInt()
        num2.toString().toInt()
        answer.setText((num1 + num2).toString())
    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
        answer.text = "Input Error"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make an integer calculator and have a problem.

```kotlin
answer.setText((num1 + num2).toString())
```

Here the addition symbol is highlighted in red. The text of the error is huge. What could be the problem?

Comment: @Tenfour04 thx, my bad, I did not change num1 and num2 to variables in the line with the summation

Answer (score 2):

Use getText() method of EditText to get the value from a EditText.

Change your code like the below

```
val value1 = num1.getText().toString().toInt()

val value2 = num1.getText().toString().toInt()

answer.setText((value1 + value2).toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

Rafiul and Tenfour04 answer above is correct.. You need to take value from edittext before converting it to string. what you do at you code is convert the whole edittext to string not the value. And I think you need a variable to contain value from edittext. So it will look like this:

```
var a = num1.getText().toString().toInt()
var b = num2.getText().toString().toInt()
answer.setText((a + b).toString())
```

Comment: There's no necessity for a variable (unless you're using it again), it just keeps the code cleaner.

Comment: @HenryTwist iam not sure. I ever see it work but why? it feels nonsense to me :v

Comment: What seems nonsense to you? `num1.getText().toString().toInt() + num2.getText().toString().toInt()`?

Comment: ohh.. I think you mean you can just change the value of num2.getText() into int(change data type of this "num2.getText()" into int directly or change its value). I ever do something like that before(my coding mistake) and it works without error. I don't know what happens till now :v

Answer (score 0):

**num1 and num 2 are EditTexts and you are adding the EditTexts.. this is the main mistake.**

From your end you are type casting the values of EditTexts but not getting the values of editText and not saving in the separate variables.

Just get & save the values in separate variables: as @Bobby suggested:

```
var a = num1.getText().toString().toInt()
var b = num2.getText().toString().toInt()
```

And then perform addition.

```
answer.setText((a + b).toString())
```